# Matching and Rebuilding URL Routes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where I have a default route template,
for example: `~/api/{area}/[controller]/{action?}/{id?}`.

My goal is to match incoming URLs with other route templates and dynamically reconstruct them with the default route template when no direct match is found.

Consider a scenario where someone sends a request like `~/{area}/api/[controller]/{action?}/{id?}`. The first call to `app.UseRouting(), EndpointRoutingMiddleware` doesn't find any match.

In such cases, I want to rebuild the path dynamically to match my default route template `(~/api/{area}/[controller]/{action?}/{id?})` and then trigger `app.UseRouting()` again to find the correct endpoint.

**Startup.cs**;

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseMiddleware<RoutingMatcherMiddleware>();

app.UseRouting();
```

**Middleware;**

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var endpointFeature = context.Features[typeof(IEndpointFeature)] as IEndpointFeature;
    var endpoint = endpointFeature?.Endpoint;

    if (endpoint != null)
    {
        return _next(context);
    }

    //My other route templates that I didn't define on my BaseApiController
    foreach (var routeTemplate in _routeTemplates)
    {
        var templateParser = TemplateParser.Parse(routeTemplate);
        var matcher = new TemplateMatcher(templateParser, null);
        var values = new RouteValueDictionary();
        if (matcher.TryMatch(context.Request.Path, values))
        {
            context.Request.Path = ReBuildRequestPath(context.Request.Path, values);
            break;
        }
    }

    return _next(context);
}
```

But this logic doesn't work properly since the second `UseRouting` overrides the request pipeline and the first one is completely ignored. And situation causes that `endpoint` is always `null` here;

```
if (endpoint != null)
{
    return _next(context);
}
```

In sum, my custom matcher is executed for every request regardless it is matched with my default template or not.

Same problem mentioned here as well;

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17210

Any idea about alternative solutions/ideas ?

**Note:** I am restricted to define all possible route templates on my BaseApiController due to performance issue on .NET 5 and this is why I am looking for a dynamic solution;

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30092

Comment: How about using [UseWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usewhenextensions.usewhen?view=aspnetcore-8.0) or [MapWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mapwhenextensions.mapwhen?view=aspnetcore-8.0) ?

Comment: I also tried UseWhen but unfortunetely, it doesn't work since Routing middleware is terminal middleware, this is from official documentation;
"...branches the request pipeline based on the result of the given predicate. Unlike with MapWhen, this branch is rejoined to the main pipeline if it doesn't short-circuit or contain a terminal middleware"

Comment: It's a different issue. [How about using 2 attributes above the Controller?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAk68.png)